# How can i rotate,zoom and scale multiple Imageview on camera surfaceview

Tags: android, camera

I am using http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/ this link code for that useful for only imageview,i want it for multiple imageview at a time

```
>package logicstree.selfitextcom;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.capricorn.RayMenu;

public class MainActivitySurfaceView extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback,OnTouchListener {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    /* Drop drag Textview */
    ImageView textImage[] = new ImageView[3];
    ViewGroup _root;
    int _xDelta;
    int _yDelta;
    // TextView Pinch Zoom

    final static float STEP = 200;
    float mRatio = 1.0f;
    int mBaseDist;
    float mBaseRatio;
    float fontsize = 13;


    private static final String TAG = "Touch";

    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f, MAX_ZOOM = 1f;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;



    private static final int[] ITEM_DRAWABLES = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };



    /*New All */
    public float[] lastEvent = null;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    public static int counterText = 0;
    Dialog dialogText;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams; 
    ArrayList<ImageView> ImageText;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativCapture);
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        ImageText = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000)
                        .show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };

        RayMenu rayMenu = (RayMenu) findViewById(R.id.ray_menu);
        final int itemCount = ITEM_DRAWABLES.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
            item.setImageResource(ITEM_DRAWABLES[i]);

            final int position = i;
            rayMenu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        openDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivitySurfaceView.this,"Create Text ..... :" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivitySurfaceView.this,
                                "position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });// Add a menu item
        }

    }

    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        // take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
        counterText=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counterText=0;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        refreshCamera();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();


        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }


    public static Bitmap drawText(String text, int textWidth, int textSize) {
        // Get text dimensions
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, textWidth,Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

        // Create bitmap and canvas to draw to
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textWidth, mTextLayout.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);



        // Draw background
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);

        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        c.drawPaint(paint);

        // Draw text
        c.save();
        c.translate(0, 0);
        mTextLayout.draw(c);
        c.restore();

        return b;
    }


    public void openDialog() {

        dialogText = new Dialog(MainActivitySurfaceView.this);
        dialogText.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialogText.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test" + counterText++, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    /*  for(final ImageView image : ImageText)

            _root.addView(image);
            image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            image.setOnTouchListener(this);
            */



        final EditText txtEdit = (EditText) dialogText.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button btnclick = (Button) dialogText.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

        btnclick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = txtEdit.getText().toString();
                int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

                //int size = (int) txtEdit.getTextSize() ;
                Bitmap bmp = drawText(name, width, 100);
                ImageView inage= new ImageView(MainActivitySurfaceView.this);

                inage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                ++counterText;
                dialogText.dismiss();
                _root.addView(inage);
                inage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                inage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                inage.setOnTouchListener(MainActivitySurfaceView.this);

            }
        });
        dialogText.show();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);

                       /* if(scale > 1.75f)
                            System.out.println("====== Scale Is : " + scale);
                        else*/
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        newRot =  rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[2];
                        float ty = values[5];
                        float sx = values[0];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        onTouchEvent(event);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }



    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
                return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("===onde");
        //bm.recycle();
        System.gc();
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }



}
```

> activity_main

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ray_menu"
            android:clickable="false" >
        </SurfaceView>

        <com.capricorn.RayMenu
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/ray_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ray_menu"
            android:id="@+id/relativCapture"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="captureImage"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Capture"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout
```

> this is my dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Enter Text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have take simply one surfaceview and using textpaint one text create and then apply upper code for move text on surfaceview...

Comment: sorry forgot add something i have convert text in bitmap then imageview and apply touch listner...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of your previous attempts to solve the problem.